Why does ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, ...) return what seems to be a reversed data stream?
This almost certainly stems from my misunderstanding of the x86 binary layout, but I was using ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, ...) to inspect a running binary, and ran into this:
Here is the text section for main:
0000000000001140 <main>:
    1140:       55                      push   %rbp
    1141:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1144:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
    1148:       c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    114f:       48 8d 3d ae 0e 00 00    lea    0xeae(%rip),%rdi        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    1156:       b0 00                   mov    $0x0,%al
    1158:       e8 d3 fe ff ff          call   1030 <printf@plt>
    115d:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    115f:       48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
    1163:       5d                      pop    %rbp
    1164:       c3                      ret

I am targeting the address 1158, and expected the call to ptrace to return: 0xe8d3feffff31c048.
However, what I am instead finding is the reversal of this, being 0x48c031fffffed3e8.
Why is this reversed? I expected PTRACE_PEEKDATA to dump 8 bytes from the requested address forward?
Like I said before this is most definitely a misunderstanding for me with how binary data is stored.
I am running Ubuntu 22.04, x86-64.
Thanks

Take the long returned and memcpy it into a char[sizeof(long)], that should be more in line with your expectations.

The data is stored as you expect, both in the program as in the register/memory. However, your debugger or printer is interpreting the 8 bytes in little-endian format for you and "helpfully" reversing the bytes.
Always use explicit byte-per-byte printing if you want to inspect things at the byte level.

Big endian as x86 is little endian

No, it is interpreting them as little endian. The first byte shows up at the little end of the number.

I think his expectations are wrong.
